# Reliability and Provability

Tags: statistics, provability, reliability

I have a system of which 700 are out on the field and one of the components is causing an issue. A new component has been sourced and I want to test it to ensure reliability. So the test I've come up with is to test this new component on 3 systems of the 700 and on each system test 5 of the new components an collect results. What is my provability of capturing a failure and how reliable is this test? in other words is it sufficient for high confidence level.

Comment: So essentially you're going to take a sample of $3$ out of $700$, and you're asking if it's sufficient?

Comment: 3 out of 700, but each one of those will be used to test 5 of the new component. So a total of 15 new components to be tested 5 on each sample.